# Is EF Core missing anything in .NET Standard vs .NET Core library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard, ef-core-2.0

I'm building an ASP.NET Core Web API project. I will be heavily using EF Core with the connection with SQL Server. I want to organize the project around 3 main tiers: Core/Logic/Domain, Data/Infrastructure and Web/API.

Web/API will be definitely a .NET Core project, but I'm struggling with the decision whether Core and Data projects should be .NET Core library or .NET Standard library.

My question is, will I lose any features or anything while building my data persistence in .NET Standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a class library, the target framework simply specifies a compatibility layer. The ultimate functionality comes from the target framework of the project that references the class library.

For example, let's say that you create a .NET Standard library, and then you include that in a .NET Framework project. Everything you do happens on .NET Framework, and for all intents and purposes you could've targeted .NET Framework from your class library as well. The choice of .NET Standard simply says that you're going to use APIs from some .NET Standard-compliant target. That's all. As a result, the functionality of something like EF Core, ultimately depends on what you drop the library into, not what framework your library targets.

As to whether to choose .NET Standard or .NET Core as the target framework for your library, simply: use .NET Standard unless you have a good reason not to. If you target .NET Standard, you can drop it into any project that targets any framework that is compatible with the version of .NET Standard your library targets. If you choose .NET Core, you can only use the library in .NET Core projects.

Things get a little murkier when you start looking at .NET Core 3.0, though. You can technically target .NET Standard 2.1 and get all the goodness of .NET Core 3.0, but nothing but .NET Core 3.0 actually supports .NET Standard 2.1. You can target .NET Standard 2.0, but then you're stuck with .NET Core 2.2. In other words, if you want to use .NET Core 3.0, right now, there's no functional different between choosing .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0 as the target framework of your library. In either case, it will only work in .NET Core 3.0 projects.

Adding even more confusion, Microsoft is moving the next version of everything under the .NET 5 umbrella. What becomes of .NET Standard at that point hasn't been discussed, by I'd imagine it largely goes away. Once there's a .NET 5, any project can target .NET 5 and be used by any other project that targets .NET 5. That's still a ways off, though. The reason I bring it up, is that if you want to use .NET Core 3.0 today, there's not much point in targeting anything but .NET Core 3.0. Most of the stuff in .NET Standard 2.1 is not back-portable to things like .NET Framework and Unity, so those will never be on .NET Standard 2.1. The path forward for those frameworks is making them .NET Core compatible, to eventually end up with .NET Core 4.0, which Microsoft will call .NET 5.

Long and short, the best performance and features are with .NET Core 3.0, as long as you can go 100% .NET Core 3.0, then that's what you should target. If you need to use your library in something like an Xamarin or .NET Framework app, then stick with .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Totally understood first 3 paragraphs. Can you rephrase 4th paragraph with .NETCore3? From what I understand .NETStandard is literally "an interface", so are you saying that Standard 2.1 and further will not be back-compatible with Standard 2 and prior?

Comment: Is this statement correct: If I implement my logic library in .NET Standard 2.0, I will not be able to simply upgrade target to .NET Standard 2.1+ and therefore WILL NOT be able to reference that library in any .NET Core 3 project. ?

Comment: It's the opposite. You can use .NET Standard 2.0 *in* .NET Core 3.0, but you can't use 3.0 stuff in .NET Standard 2.0. Since we're talking about EF Core here, that means you could only use EF Core 2.2, not EF Core 3.0 in your library, regardless of whether it's going into a .NET Core 3.0 project.

Comment: Gotcha, so the safest way is it start with .NETStandard 2.0 for `Core` and `Data` libraries and `.NETCore` for WebApi project. Do what I need to do in these libraries. If everything works, I will stay with .NETStandard for libraries, while upgrading only WebApi project to .NETCore3 and further future versions. When I reach the point where .NETCore WebApi needs higher .NETStandard, I'm gonna upgrade my libraries. In other words, I'm gonna keep libraries low, while webapi project - high. I hope I expressed myself clearly

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, having a library that targets .NETStandard 2.0, means that even in the future I will be able to use that library in the future .NET5 projects as well as in old .NET4.6 Framework projects. Correct?

Comment: Yes. You can always use lower versions in higher versions. Using a lower version just constricts the API footprint, so you can't use all the bells and whistles (`Span<T>`, etc.)

Comment: Gotcha, so technically, the most advanced target for library that can be consumed by .NET Framework and .NET Core apps is .NET Standard 2.0. You could say "the last true .net standard" :)) Thanks Chris, you helped me a lot

Comment: Yeah, basically. I mean is possible that there may be an intervening point before .NET 5 where other frameworks support .NET Standard 2.1. I just don't see it as likely.

Answer (score 1):

From the [.NET Standard Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

> The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations.

From the [.NET Core Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/)

> .NET Core is an open-source, general-purpose development platform

What this means in relation to your question.

Creating a .NET Standard library, you would be able to pull that library into a .NET Core project or a .NET Framework project assuming that the .NET Core/Framework project would adhere to the same .NET Standard version of your library or greater. So, the .NET Standard library would give you more flexibility regarding the projects you would be able to pull that library into(good if this needs to be pulled into legacy applications running on .NET Framework >=4.6.1 as well as new applications that would be written in .NET Core).

The only hiccup I've encountered with this approach is regarding migrations. If you want to use EFCore Migrations through the `dotnet ef` commands, it expects you to target a project with a .NET Core version. So, if you create your `DbContext` in the .NET Standard library and want to create migrations from it, you will either have to give it a startup project that is a .NET Core project or implement a '[Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)'. As an aside, this last option does have a few limitations, one of which is documented in an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8332).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not gonna use migrations actually. If the only potential problem are migrations, and there is a walk-around already, I'm gonna try .NET Standard library. Thanks for help